# d3 x axis labels outputted as long string

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to rotate my x-axis label for a d3 stacked histogram I created in d3. All of the labels are either displayed as a long string or all on top of each other.

Here's my label code:

```
var shortNames = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"];

// Add a label per experiment.
var label = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(shortNames)
.enter().append("svg:text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d)+x.rangeBand()/2; })
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.text(function(d) {return d})
.attr("transform", function(d) {    // transform all the text elements
return "rotate(-65)"            // rotate them to give a nice slope
});
```

I played around with the translate function and all of the labels are still treated as one long string. How do I apply translate to each individual label?

I can play around with the margins later, but for now I want to have control over my labels.

[image: Illustration of problem with x-axis label]

Comment: Have you tried `.data([shortNames])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the order of transforms: When you rotate the text, you're also rotating its coordinate system. So when you set its x position –– even though you're setting the position earlier than the rotation transform –- you're actually moving it along the 65 degree axis resulting from the rotation.

If I'm correct about this, then inspecting the labels would reveal that they're still made up of multiple text elements (one per label), rather than one text element for all labels.

As a rule, when you introduce a `transform` attribute as you did for `rotate`, you should do all your transformation via this attribute. So, you need to use `translate` instead of using the `"x"` attribute. Then it would look like this:

```
var label = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(shortNames)
.enter().append("svg:text")
// REOVE THIS: .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d)+x.rangeBand()/2; })
// AND THIS TOO: .attr("y", 6)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.text(function(d) {return d})
.attr("transform", function(d) {    // transform all the text elements
  return "translate(" + // First translate
    x(d)+x.rangeBand()/2 + ",6) " + // Translation params same as your existing x & y 
    "rotate(-65)"            // THEN rotate them to give a nice slope
});
```