# d3 - Rotate text elements in an array

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to use selectAll("text") in d3 to to add an array of string values (called 'data') to my graph. I want each individual data point to be rotated at the point it is placed at, defined here as (i * (width/ data.length) + 8, 170). However, it is currently rotating the entire array set as one long string, with the first element at the (x, y) point I set. How can I appropriately apply the translate rotation to rotate each element individually?

```
  new_svg.selectAll("text")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
             return i * (width / data.length) + 8;
          })
         .attr("y", function(d) { 
             return 170;
         })
        .attr("dx", -barWidth/2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Garamond, sans-serif")
        .text(function(d) { return d;})
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(45)"
        });
```

Comment: This sounds like there's actually only one `text` element in the first place. Did you verify that there are in fact several `text` elements?

Answer (score 0):

There was more than one text element in the array, which I was able to verify. It turns out that the problem comes from setting the x and y elements separate from the translate transform. The solution offered here worked for me: [[d3 x axis labels outputted as long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419670/d3-x-axis-labels-outputted-as-long-string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419670/d3-x-axis-labels-outputted-as-long-string)